# extract from json object thats converte to array php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I try to extract data from an json object.

I mannaged to convert the json object to an array but  i can't extract the data i want 
The array and var_dump can be found here http://pastebin.com/f1ujbSCq

if you look in the array at object->object->attributes-attribute

You see values in the object class.
for example i want the the value where the name in the onject class is descr or admin-c,tech-c.

But i can't figer out how to do that

THis is the php code i use to extract data from json object to an array:

```
$domeinnaam = "2.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.8.6.9.0.2.0.a.2.ip6.arpa";
$ripeinfo = haalripezone($domeinnaam);


var_dump($ripeinfo);
print_r($ripeinfo);


function haalripezone ($domeinnaam)
{

$link = "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/domain/$domeinnaam.json";
$downloadlink = file_get_contents($link);
$result = json_decode($downloadlink);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You see values in the object class. for example i want the the value
>   where the name in the onject class is descr or admin-c,tech-c.

Since you have already decoded the JSON as an object, You could access your fields like this..

```
echo $yourObject->objects->attributes->attribute->name; //"prints" admin-c
```

You could alternatively loop through using a `foreach` construct..

```
<?php
$domeinnaam = "2.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.8.6.9.0.2.0.a.2.ip6.arpa";
$ripeinfo = haalripezone($domeinnaam);
echo "<pre>";
foreach($ripeinfo->objects->object[0]->attributes->attribute as $attr)
{
    echo $attr->name."<br>";
}


function haalripezone ($domeinnaam)
{

    $link = "https://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/domain/$domeinnaam.json";
   //$downloadlink = file_get_contents($link);
    $downloadlink = '{"objects":{"object":[{"type":"domain","link":{"type":"locator","href":"http://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/domain/2.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.8.6.9.0.2.0.a.2.ip6.arpa"},"source":{"grs-mirror":[],"id":"ripe"},"primary-key":{"attribute":[{"name":"domain","value":"2.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.8.6.9.0.2.0.a.2.ip6.arpa"}]},"attributes":{"attribute":[{"name":"domain","value":"2.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.8.6.9.0.2.0.a.2.ip6.arpa"},{"name":"descr","value":"Reverse delegation for Glue network ipv6 tunnel server"},{"name":"nserver","value":"ns3.hobby.nl"},{"name":"nserver","value":"ns2.hobby.nl"},{"name":"nserver","value":"ns1.hobby.nl"},{"link":{"type":"locator","href":"http://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/role/HNET2-RIPE"},"name":"admin-c","value":"HNET2-RIPE","referenced-type":"role"},{"link":{"type":"locator","href":"http://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/role/HNET2-RIPE"},"name":"tech-c","value":"HNET2-RIPE","referenced-type":"role"},{"link":{"type":"locator","href":"http://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/role/HNET2-RIPE"},"name":"zone-c","value":"HNET2-RIPE","referenced-type":"role"},{"link":{"type":"locator","href":"http://rest.db.ripe.net/ripe/mntner/HOBBYNET-RIPE-MNT"},"name":"mnt-by","value":"HOBBYNET-RIPE-MNT","referenced-type":"mntner"},{"name":"source","value":"RIPE","comment":"Filtered"}]},"tags":{"tag":[]}}]},"terms-and-conditions":{"type":"locator","href":"http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf"}}';
    $result = json_decode($downloadlink);
    return $result;
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
domain
descr
nserver
nserver
nserver
admin-c
tech-c
zone-c
mnt-by
source
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/105493)

Comment: Still not work see: http://pastebin.com/rLEdfbc0 PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /root/ripe-client/download-xml.php on line 8
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /root/ripe-client/download-xml.php on line 8
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /root/ripe-client/download-xml.php on line 8
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /root/ripe-client/download-xml.php on line 8
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /root/ripe-client/download-xml.php on line 8

Comment: Can you give a shot now ?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  $result = json_decode($downloadlink, true);
```

This way the decode will be totally put into an array, then accessing the data will be easier

Comment: Oke that get rid of the object classes witch is good but when i try to extract the data with an 
   foreach $inhoud = $ripeinfo->objects->object->attributes->attribute;
   foreach ($inhoud as $inhoudend) it doesn't work
{
 echo $inhoudend[name];
}